# Can i install windows XP after installing windows 8.1

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8.1, windows-installation

I have windows 8.1 on my system. I want to install windows xp on another partition but i searched and found that previous version of windows should be installed first otherwise it might not work.

Is there any way to install xp after windows 8.1?

Comment: You can;  If you do;  You will also have to repair the Windows 8.1 bootloader.  Which is the reason your always suppose to install XP first then 8.1.

Answer (score 3):

You can.

Just make sure that you create the partition for XP using a tool like MiniTool Partition Wizard or GParted Live  on the end bit of your HDD (you might need to resize the larger Windows 8.1 partition).

Boot up your Windows XP CD and install it to the newly created partition. But since you're installing XP after 8.1, the 8.1 boot sector will be overwritten by the XP one so you need to re-install it using a tool like BootICE (http://bbs.ipauly.com/)

Also, here's a tutorial that's for installing XP after 7 using different tools (Windows Disk Management and EasyBCD) that might be easier for a regular user to follow (http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8790/dual-boot-your-pre-installed-windows-7-computer-with-xp/)

Comment: Is re-sizing partition safe? is there any chance i lost my data?

Comment: You should always have a backup of your data.